# Tomcat process suddenly crushes

Tags: java, linux, jvm, tomcat6

Trying to diagnose some bizarre Tomcat 6 and/or JVM errors on a 64-bit linux machine:

> OS VERSION                       : RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX SERVER RELEASE 6.3 (SANTIAGO)
>   SERVER MODEL                     : VMWARE VIRTUAL PLATFORM ()

I am running some application tests on virtual machines and facing a weird issue.
The problem occures on certain VMs where exactly 2 process are running: Tomcat Application server process (java process) and a monitor process, at one randomal point, after some random hours of execution the following message can be found on catalina.out (server log) of the VM that fails (the problem doesnt occurs always on same machine):

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-50100
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

After this moment the Tomcat process is shutted down and execution fails.
No picks can be seen on memory or CPU use.
No system messages can be seen under /var/logs.

1. At first stage we suspected that an external signal is killing our Tomcat process and we tried to use the `-Xrs` flag for JVM arguments of the process but issue still occurred.

   The java flag (`-xrs` ) should prevent the Java runtime environment handling exception signals such `SIGSEGV` and `SIGABRT` not help

   Before adding `xrs` flag we saw `INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-50100` error that happened because outcome signal

   After adding `xrs flag the kettle/tomcat behaves the same way and crushes without any errors in log files.
2. Running starce command on relevant process gives us the following output:

   Process 12917 attached - interrupt to quit
   futex(0x7f6b9e8ab9d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 12918, NULLPANIC: attached pid 12917 exited with 143

   We cannot run `starce -f` to include all threads because it causes our application to be stuck.
    However, killing son process with `kill` command behaves similary - we see that parent JVM
    exit with error code 143 and we see also the signal sent to the son process.
3. We are running also with java `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` optind to create a heap dump for jvm crash due to out of memory error but no core dump or heap dumps are creted due to the crush.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure they found a solution - but this thread has a similar sounding issue - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.tomcat.user/206745

Comment: Is Tomcat receiving requests when crashing? Does it crash without deployed applications?

Comment: I have run my process now with strace on signals and got following output: 
1 Process 24631 attached - interrupt to quit
2 --- SIGRT_2 (Real-time signal 0) @ 0 (0) ---
3 rt_sigreturn(0x7fe4d8b39850)            = 202
4 PANIC: attached pid 24631 exited with 143                                                                 Regarding the request i am not sure, actually in server log we can see a sore of request to shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

is it possible, that before the crash, there is some sort of memory depletion, so that the java process could be killed by the OOM.
Also, I found a link http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=4059 that describes a similar problem.

Comment: After running process with -Xdump flag we got dump files but it seems that they do not contain any usefull information. All monitor tools on env didnt shows us any problem with memory.